# validates_presence_of unless other is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My users can choose between using an image url or uploading an image. One of both is required though.

How can I use `validates_presence_of :url` with an "unless `:image` is used". And vice versa.

I've managed to get this to work; But obviously this doesn't work. Because it will add the validation if the other one isn't present. I'm confused in to how to get ONLY ONE of both to be entered.

```
validates_presence_of       :url, if: Proc.new { |a| a.pictogram.blank? }
validates_presence_of       :pictogram, if: Proc.new { |a| a.url.blank? }
```

**EDIT:**
I fixed it with

`validate :addImageValidation`

```
def addImageValidation
    if !url.blank? && !image.blank?
        errors.add(:image, "both not empty")
    end
end
```

Comment: You can use fewer operators with `if url.blank? == image.blank?`, easier to read that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own validator:

```
validate :url_or_pictogram_but_not_both

def url_or_pictogram_but_not_both
  unless url ^ pictogram
    errors.add ...
  end
end
```

Comment: It's the xor operator. Exclusive-or: one and only one of the values must be true.